# Is there a way to force dragend event when dragging a marker on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I've got a draggable marker on map and when I get to a defined position (which I've already defined) I want the browser to stop the dragging by executing dragend event without user dropping the marker himself. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind to marker's drag event and when marker is at your desired position, you set marker's draggable option to false. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mBjbp/).

```
var aroundPrague = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.69537977711389, 13.93707275390625),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.400843232947864, 15.17303466796875)
);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function(ev) {
    if (aroundPrague.contains(ev.latLng)) {
        marker.draggable = false;
    }
});
```